# Ati HD 6400M /Intel HD300 Ubuntu 12.04 OpenGl Problem

Tags: ati, intel, fglrx, opengl

After installing ATI Catalyst I can't run Unity 3D on Integrated Intel graphics.
On dedicated everyting runs ok, the only problem is it looks like it doesn't support openGL vertext buffer.

Unity test:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

OpenGL vendor string:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string:  1.4 (3.0 Mesa 8.0.2)

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  no
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

my xorg:

```
Section "ServerLayout"  
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"  
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0  
EndSection  

    Section "Module"
        Load  "glx"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
    EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    DefaultDepth     24
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I can't find any solution to this problem. Thank you for all support!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.
It was enough to edit /etc/X11/Xsession.d/10fglrx

```
gksu gedit /etc/X11/Xsession.d/10fglrx
```

If you're using a 32bits system add at the end of 4th line this text : "/usr/lib32/dri/" without the quotes. The file should now look like this :

```
    LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/fglrx/dri 
if [ `uname -m` = 'x86_64' ]; then 
if [ -d /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri ]; then 
LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=${LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH}:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib32/dri
if [ ! -z $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ]; then 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
fi 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}/usr/lib32 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
fi 
fi 
export LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH
```

If you're using a 64bits system add at the end of 4th line this text : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/" without the quotes. The file should now look like this :

```
LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/fglrx/dri 
if [ `uname -m` = 'x86_64' ]; then 
if [ -d /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri ]; then 
LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=${LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH}:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri
if [ ! -z $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ]; then 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
fi 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}/usr/lib32
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
fi 
fi 
export LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH
```

Now save the file.

Reboot your computer to see the changes, it should boot up with the discrete card.
Solution from [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450) Look at **STEP 2**